# API - How can I let API-users declare their own types (which are then used by the API)?

Tags: java, android, api

I want to create a library (for own use to begin with but maybe for publishing later so I want to do it the proper way).

I'll use following (abstract) example to explain my question:

```
public void onSomeEvent(SomeEvent someEvent) {
    String action = someEvent.getAction();

    EventTypes eventTypes = getEventTypes(); //problem lies with this method

    for (EventType eventType : eventTypes) {
        if (eventType.getAction().equals(action)) {
            eventType.onEvent(someEvent);
        }
    }
}

private EventTypes getEventTypes {
    //User should have defined his own event-type-classes by extending EventType:
    //What is the best way to let the user list/define these EventTypes 
    //so my API can access them (e.g. with this method)?  
}
```

My question is as shown in the comment of the example:

What is the best way to let the user of my API define his own EventTypes for this EventReceiver of the API while meeting (in best case all of the) following criteria:

- event-types are easy to define for users
- not using reflection
- user-types are not registered at runtime, but statically listed somewhere (without annotation-processor)

I don't know if these creteria can all be fulfilled (I guess not).

But if you neglect one or more of the criteria (the first one shouldn't be in any case), please explain to me why there is no better way of doing it (without writing my own annotation-processor).

I hope my question is clear.
If you think it isn't, please suggest me how to make it more precise.

If you think I'm missing out something or should make an entirely different approach, I'd be glad for your corrections.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use Java generics to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a new interface the user of your api can implement:

```
public interface EventType {
    String getAction ();
    [...]
}
```

And then implement your get method to access the event types to following way. You will then also need a list as a member of your class and a method to add new EventTypes:

```
private List<EventType> eventTypes = new List<>();

public void addEventType (EventType type) {
    this.eventTypes.add(type);
}

public List<EventType> getEventTypes() {
    return this.eventTypes;
}
```

The user of your API is than able to define new EventTypes by creating new classes implementing your interface.

Comment: I have to admit that your third criteria is not met by this approach.

Comment: I will have to accept that, because, as @kris commented, there is no way around doing it at runtime without getting into reflection and annotations. Thanks

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks. I would have really liked to participate in your conversation, but unfortunately I have to wait until I have enough reputation to do so. In addition @Kris emailxpressed it way better than I could have.

Answer (score 4):

```
    public List<? extends EventType> getEventTypes() {
        ...
    }
```

Time to learn about Generics, my friend:

[Lesson: Generics (Updated) (The Java Tutorials > Learning the Java Language)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: I know what Generics are - so what you suggest is to let user override `getEventTypes()` and let him return a list of `EventType`s. But then user would have to instantiate a new ArrayList and add the types "manually" and return them. Is that the way you would do this? That'd be really simple.

Comment: My answer is based on this line of code: `for (EventType eventType : eventTypes) {` -- yes, this is how I would do this.  But first I want to make sure I'm completely understanding you.  Can you explain about the action? Because I'm a little puzzled by this line:   `if (eventType.getAction().equals(action)) {`

Comment: Every event (SomeEvent and EventType) has its action so the API can determine to which event-type to send the "`SomeEvent`". Well then thanks, that was much simpler than I thought :)

Comment: Just be careful about over-engineering this.  Clients use your library; events happen; there are data associated with those events.  All you need to do is define an interface that passes the client that event data and let them define the implementation they need.  Then allow the client to register for the event.  In that sense, @CodeLionX 's answer is a little more accurate for your situation.  IMHO, using a string to determine an action is not as clear as a specific interface method for that action.

Comment: And BTW, if `EventType` is an `interface`, you don't really need the generic typing.

Comment: But now, if the user overrides getEventTypes(), there is no way I can know how he named his class to call the method. And if I use @CodeLionX's answer, the user has to add the event-types at runtime, that would be when the application initialises. I wouldn't like the user to undertake this procedure... Is there really no way for not doing this at runtime?

Comment: That's the beauty of the interface -- _you don't need to know anything else about the client's implementation class._  You are only going to deal with the instance of the client class by using the interface and calling one of its methods, the definition of which you have complete control over.  This is the standard Inversion of Control pattern.

Comment: Example: I wrote a pinch-zoom image view where I used the `ScaleGestureDetector`.  So I implemented the `OnScaleGestureListener` interface and passed it to the `ScaleGestureDetector`.  `ScaleGestureDetector` has no idea what class I passed it, other than the fact that it implements `OnScaleGestureListener` so it can call `onScale()` when the user pinch-zooms.  The interface is a _contract_ between your API and the client.  All you require is that the client conform to your contract.  You don't need anything else.

Comment: You _passed_ the listener-interface to the detector. The equivalent in my example would be that the user _passes_ the event-type (be it interface or abstract class) to the API somehow. That would be the same as CodeLionXs. But is there a way to let my API _retrieve_ the types and not let the user do the initialization? Anyway, thanks for your efforts to help me :)

Comment: Not without getting into reflection and annotations, which you've ruled out.  Besides, those techniques add a lot of complexity and risk of defects on your part for a small benefit on the client's part.  Registering implementation instances are a pretty standard thing in Java and Android.  I don't think it's unreasonable to require an API client to add a couple extra lines of code on their side in order to get the benefit of your API.

Comment: I don't have a choice then, as it seems, ok. So I will tick CodeLionX's answer because theres no other way than doing it like he suggested. But you helped me a lot, thanks.